# Java's executionService.shutdownNow() not cancelling or interrupting thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, future, executorservice

This code is permanently blocking on `future.get()`. I would have expected a `CancellationException` or an `InterruptedException`. Can anyone explain this?

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

es.execute(() -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {/*squelch*/}
});

Future<Integer> future = es.submit(() -> 1);
es.shutdownNow();
try {
    future.get();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow--) say there are no guarantees, but I still find the observed behaviour strange because it implies that failures to stop are caused by misbehaved threads. In this case there doesn't seem to be any attempt to stop the thread.

> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.

Comment: The `future` task never gets started, the first task does get interrupted though. So there is an attempt to stop the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this case there doesn't seem to be any attempt to stop the thread.

It tries to stop running `Runnables`. In this case, that's probably the one that's sleeping. It's going to be interrupted, and you'll catch the exception and return. The nop `Runnable` is still in the queue.

You wouldn't get an `InterruptedException` unless the thread calling `future.get()` were interrupted.

`CancellationException` would be reasonable to expect, except *technically*, you didn't cancel the Future, you shut down the executor.

The *intended* use seems to be that you retail the list of `Runnables` `shutdownNow()` returns so you can run them. That works, but you can't check them against what you've submitted because they've actually been decorated (but you don't know this, and it's kinda a surprise that it doesn't return the references you submitted).

There's two bad workarounds to get this functionality: track the futures you got back and cancel them yourself or cast the `Runnables` that were returned by `shutdownNow()` to Futures and cancel them, but that only works because that happens to be the internal implementation of the executor you're using.

So yes, that's the behavior, it's *technically* right, but it's a little weird. What are you trying to accomplish, here?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Re: "What are you trying to accomplish" ... nothing. I was just playing around.